# JavaScript, Tampermonkeys - how to make an array out of strings in an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome

I want to convert the names of months into numbers and store the month in a table's cell on a webpage. I figured having it as an array would let me refer to the month names by their array numbers and I could insert table tags before and after them. I got as far as replacing the month names:

```
var dates = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
    for(var i = 0, l = dates.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        var date = dates[i];
        date.innerHTML = date.innerHTML.replace('Aug', '08');
    }
```

The relevant html segment looks like

```
<span class="date">Mon&nbsp;2017.&nbsp;Aug&nbsp;28&nbsp;15:25:13</span>
```

which I'd like to turn into

```
<span class="date"><table><tbody><tr><td>Mon&nbsp;</td><td>2017.&nbsp;08&nbsp;28&nbsp;15:25:13</td></tr></tbody></table></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use "& nbsp;" as split "Character", try something like this.

```js
var dates = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
    for(var i = 0, l = dates.length; i < l; i++)
    {
     var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tbody = document.createElement("tbody")
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var date = dates[i];
        var string = date.innerHTML.replace('Aug', '08.');
        var split = string.split("&nbsp;");
                
        
         for(var j = 0; j < split.length; j++){
          var td = document.createElement("td");
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(split[j]));
          tr.appendChild(td);
         }
    
        date.innerHTML="";
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        table.appendChild(tbody);
    
        date.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<span class="date">Mon&nbsp;2017.&nbsp;Aug&nbsp;28&nbsp;15:25:13</span>
```

Comment: How to group everything after split[0] to make only 2 cells, one with the day of the week and the other with the date?

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for showing that site. Last question, how to replace

    var string = date.innerHTML.replace('Aug', '08.');

with something that looks for a variable instead of 'Aug'? I tried split[3] before, but didn't work.

Comment: And I'd like to keep the spaces, so I'd have to edit all of them, I assume. Edit: nevermind, figured the spaces out.